# how gabor filter is used on image texture edge detection

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection, gabor, texture

as I searched gabor filter is most used tool on texture analysis and edge detection in digital image. its said that it searches a certain frequency as a texure around a pixel or point to find the texture. I cant really understand it well. as I know frequency in digital image is sign of change in grayscale change. high frequency has high change in grayscale so a highpass filter finds the edges but I cant understand a filter like gabor can find a special texture.

thank you for helping

Comment: question please. how gabor filter must detect motion in sequence images, and what the mean of temporal frequency, is that signifiy the speed of motion and how detect it ? any one have a answer of this. thank you advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A periodic geometrical texture may appear as a localized wiggling pattern, with dominant orientations and 2D frequencies. Its correlation with Gabor atoms is bigger when the atom has orientation and frequencies close to the texture's, thus yielding feature vectors allowing texture detection or classification.